# tell chrome to load different URLs in each tab using commandline

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

Say I have these URLs:
1-> www.google.com
2-> www.bing.com
3-> www.something.com

I want to open them in tabs relative to their numbers:
tab 1-> www.google.com
tab 2-> www.bing.com
tab 3-> www.something.com

and after that I will need to load these 3 other URLs:
1-> www.learn.com
2-> www.somethingelse.com
3-> www.thirdwebsite.com
-----------
I don't want to open new tabs, but I want to load them in the opened tabs as follows:
tab 1-> www.learn.com
tab 2-> www.somethingelse.com
tab 3-> www.thirdwebsite.com

----------
also I want the developer tools to be opened and stay open for these three tabs always.

any solutions?
It would be great if I could do all of the above without bringing google chrome to front. I'd like it to stay at the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to open them in tabs relative to their numbers

Add the 3 urls to the chrome command line.

Example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.google.com www.bing.com www.microsoft.com
```

Result (after restoring Chrome from the taskbar):

[image]

---

#### I don't want to open new tabs, but I want to load them in the opened tabs

This is not currently possible and there is an [open bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=661125) request for this. It is currently "Status: Untriaged":

> **Command line option "target" to open a URL in the same named tab or window**
>
> Reported by mpiet...@gmail.com, Nov 1 2016
>
> UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71
>   Safari/537.36
>
> Steps to reproduce the problem:
>
> 1. open a URL with Chrome via command line with options.
> 2. specify a "target" just like you would via an anchor reference in a web page.
> 3. Chrome opens a new tab if the named target does not exist, or re-uses the existing tab if it does.
>
> What is the expected behavior?
>
> Chrome opens a new tab if the named
>   target does not exist, or re-uses the existing tab if it does.  It
>   should also understand the standard target parameter _blank which is
>   the current behavior of just opening a new tab.  The other standard
>   parameters _self, _parent, and _top are meaningless in this context
>   and should provide the current behavior.
>
> I'd also propose that the existing option --new-window does not open a
>   new window if a window with the named target already exists (i.e. not
>   tabbed) but rather re-uses the existing window.  Thus a user could
>   re-use a target-named window or re-use a target-named tab via that
>   switch.
>
> What went wrong? Chrome just opens a new tab regardless.
>
> Did this work before? No
>
> Chrome version: 54.0.2840.71  Channel: stable OS Version: 10.0 Flash
>   Version: Shockwave Flash 23.0 r0
>
> See previous  issue 141942  for more comments.  It was
>   Automated-archive but clearly has continued interest.

---

#### I want the developer tools to be opened and stay open for these three tabs always

You [already asked this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1216459/how-to-tell-chrome-to-open-developer-tools-for-specific-website-domains).

Comment: if it is not completely possible in chrome, can we do these steps in Firefox?

Comment: @acman123 The first is the same as chrome. The second is [possbile with an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055148/select-a-tab-in-firefox-from-command-line). The third maybe possible using the `-devtools` command line option (Start with native Developer Tools opened) - I haven't tested it.

Comment: the solution is not for activating tabs by their number, rather its by searching the title of tabs. is there any solution for doing it by tab numbers?

Comment: @acman123 I've no idea. It's not something I've ever wanted to do. Perhaps you should ask a new question targeting Firefox.